# Rails: How to have the locale in links inside emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, internationalization

How can I have Rails automatically include the locale in every link in every email?

I want:

```
http://www.some-company.com/en/welcome
```

...instead of just...

```
http://www.some-company.com/welcome
```

I just know that for normal views, it would be:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  def self.default_url_options(options={})
    options.merge({ locale: I18n.locale })
  end

  ...
end
```

But how is this achieved for email views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you put something like `self.class.default_url_options[:locale] = my_locale` in your mailer methods. You'll have to set that `my_locale` somehow - maybe pass it as an argument to the mailer method.

Comment: So it'd have to be set in every mail method, then. It's a shame Rails doesn't include the locale in links automatically when one's already using ```I18n.with_locale(@recipient.locale) do mail(from:..., to:...) end```.